# Duplicate class com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0(core-3.1.0.jar)and jetified-core-3.5.0(com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, flutter-dependencies

my dependencies in app/app/build.gradle

dependencies {
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"

```
def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'])
coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.3.0@aar'
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.5.1'
```

}

after add implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.5.1' to app/build.gradle, when i try to build i get the error below

Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDevelopmentDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.Binarizer found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.ChecksumException found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.DecodeHintType found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.Dimension found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.EncodeHintType found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.FormatException found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.InvertedLuminanceSource found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.LuminanceSource found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.MultiFormatWriter found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.NotFoundException found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.PlanarYUVLuminanceSource found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.RGBLuminanceSource found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.Reader found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.ReaderException found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.Result found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.ResultMetadataType found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.ResultPoint found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.ResultPointCallback found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.Writer found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.WriterException found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.aztec.AztecDetectorResult found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.aztec.AztecReader found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.aztec.AztecWriter found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.aztec.decoder.Decoder found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.aztec.decoder.Decoder$Table found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.aztec.detector.Detector found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.aztec.detector.Detector$Point found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.aztec.encoder.AztecCode found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.aztec.encoder.BinaryShiftToken found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.aztec.encoder.Encoder found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.aztec.encoder.HighLevelEncoder found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.aztec.encoder.HighLevelEncoder$1 found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.aztec.encoder.SimpleToken found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.aztec.encoder.State found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.aztec.encoder.Token found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.client.result.AbstractDoCoMoResultParser found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.client.result.AddressBookAUResultParser found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.client.result.AddressBookDoCoMoResultParser found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.client.result.AddressBookParsedResult found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.client.result.BizcardResultParser found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.client.result.BookmarkDoCoMoResultParser found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.client.result.CalendarParsedResult found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.client.result.EmailAddressParsedResult found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.client.result.EmailAddressResultParser found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.client.result.EmailDoCoMoResultParser found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.client.result.ExpandedProductParsedResult found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.client.result.ExpandedProductResultParser found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.client.result.GeoParsedResult found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.client.result.GeoResultParser found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.client.result.ISBNParsedResult found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.client.result.ISBNResultParser found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.zxing.client.result.ParsedResult found in modules jetified-core-3.1.0 (core-3.1.0.jar) and jetified-core-3.5.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0)

deleted .gradle
updated gradle
flutter clean
flutter pub cache repair
flutter upgrade
flutter pub get
./gradlew clean

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Try This one,

```
implementation ('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0') { transitive false }
```

Comment: have added 
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"

    def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'])
    implementation ('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.3.0') { transitive false }
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.5.1'
}

am still getting the same error